# UdpClient.() vs UdpClient(port)

Tags: c#, udp

I have a little problem and a Solution, but i would like to understand whats happening exactly. 
Depending on the constructor of UdpClient I use EndReceive() throws a Socket Exeption or not( 10054 - An existing connection got closed by the remote host (translated from german))

thanks for any hint!
Vincent

```
private UdpClient udpClient;

    void recv(IAsyncResult res)
    {
        IPEndPoint remote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        byte[] data = udpClient.EndReceive(res, ref remote); // code stops here in debug

        // do something with data received from remote

        udpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //udpClient = new UdpClient(); // will throw exception
        udpClient = new UdpClient(8000); // will not throw exception
        udpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8000);
        udpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        udpClient.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hallo"), 5);
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting an exception? At the `BeginReceive`  call? I have tried your sample and can start it without an exception

Comment: No, the code stops at EndReceive, did you change the used constructor in form1_load? i posted the working code, so for the error you would have to change it

Answer (score 1):

case 1: udpClient = new UdpClient() - you binding socket to random local port
case 2: udpClient = new UdpClient(8000) - you binding socket to local port 8000

Maybe in case 1 remote host try send to random port and rejected by firewall?

Comment: you are right! i did not think about the local port because of the specific port in the connect() function. thanks alot